# Cannot hide navigation bar from inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation-bar

I currently have a ViewPager with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. The problem here is that a navigation bar appears whenever I click a button, so I started manually hiding it with the following code:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

This code snippet works fine inside an activity, but doesn't do anything in a fragment. For all similar stackoverflow answers, they recommend to add getActivty() like below:

```
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()………..
```

BUT FOR SOME REASON IT IS STILL NOT HIDING THE NAVIGATION BAR

Comment: You guys should be explaining when you down-vote a question or answer, so that others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After failing for a couple of days to solve this problem, I finally decided to go back and read the android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#EnableFullscreen). So I solved the problem by enabling sticky immersive mode whenever activity's window focus is changed, like below:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
// I removed the below condition check because I still want to hide System UI even if activity
// loses focus. Such cases include spinner dropdown list is open, dialog box is displayed, etc.
// if(hasFocus)
    hideSystemUI();
}

private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Enables sticky immersive mode.
    // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY.
    // Or for "regular immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                    // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

// Shows the system bars by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
private void showSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

**Note**: The reason why I enabled sticky immersive mode instead of the regular immersive mode is that with regular immersive mode, non-translucent navigation bar will be permanently displayed when user gestures from bottom to top. But with sticky immersive mode, a translucent navigation bar will be temporarily displayed.

**Update**: I forgot to link this to the question. Since the onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) will be triggered even if the focus changes are caused by a fragment task, there is no need to hide the System UI from inside the fragment.

Answer (score 2):

In fragments, first get the Activity's context, and then over that context hide the soft navigation keys..

```
getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Add this piece of code in your fragment's `onCreateView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

As Viewpager calls multiple fragments at same time, viewpager height can't be changed. Hence there won't be any effect of it. So its better to handle it from activity or fragment that holds viewpager.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do, handle it from the fragment. But as I said, no success.

Comment: are you trying to do it from the fragments inside view pager or outside viewpager? It should be handled outside view pager